# Security error message key translations possibilities (to dutch)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I've been looking for all the error message key translations so can translate them all to dutch.
The docu explains the following

```
'Invalid credentials.': 'The password you entered was invalid!'
```

So how to "translate" invalid credentials.
I want to change all the error message to dutch or make own texts.
I already change the default langue to nl:

```
framework:
default_locale: nl
translator:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
    fallbacks:
        - en
```

But where can i find all the possibilites like: Invalid credentials. i googled a lot but cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations) each bundle can have its own translation files in Resources/translation. For the symfony security bundle the path is vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Resources/translations ([Github](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/tree/master/Resources/translations)). There is even a file for dutch. Copy and paste the file to your translations folder and adjust it or override only some. If you configured the locale correctly the error messages should be in dutch.